# Perl/bash script to generate a HTML Page

Tags: perl, bash, fonts, scripting

I have a text file "font.txt" containing the name of all the fonts in the system (you can use "fc-list" or something to get that list), one font name per line. I want to generate a html page containing a sample world like "Hello World" printed for every font in that list. I know it could be done manually but the list of fonts is over 400 and I'm looking for a bash or perl script for the task. Any help is appreciated.

PS. I haven't attached any code as I'm not sure where I should plug in the html code in a bash script.

Comment: Could you show how the resulting html file would look like for, let's say, 5 fonts ? And can you also show how you think you would get and incorporate a line from the fc-list ? That would be very convenient for the one who is going to help you out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same folder as your font.txt, create the generateHTML.pl script. Run the script in a terminal using "perl generateHTML.pl". It should generate a new file called "output.html" which you can open in a browser.

Example font.txt

```
verdana
arial
impact
```

generateHTML.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open OUTFILE, ">output.html";
open INFILE, "<font.txt";

my @fonts = <INFILE>;

print OUTFILE qq|<html><head></head><body>| . "\n";

foreach (@fonts){
    chomp;
    print OUTFILE qq|<p style="font-family:| . $_ . qq|;">Hello, world</p>| ."\n";
}

print OUTFILE qq|</body></html>|;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the system fonts from fc-list have anything to do with what will display on a remote system browser.